# Sorting and DataModel – CollectionDataModel, what is the use of setRowIndex()?

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2, datamodel

Each collection (`List`, `HashMap` and so on) is wrapped by JSF in a `DataModel` class (or, in a subclass, as `ArrayDataModel`, `CollectionDataModel`, `ListDataModel`, `ResultDataModel`, `ResultSetDataModel`, or `ScalarDataModel`). JSF will call the table `DataModel` class' methods when it renders/decodes table data.

I am trying to build an example given in Anghel Leonard's book - Mastering Java Server Faces 2.2

The bean is as simple as this one:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PlayersBean implements Serializable {

    private HashSet<Players> dataHashSet = new HashSet<>();
    private SortDataModel<Players> sortDataModel;    
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    private String sortType = "asc";

    public PlayersBean() {
        try {
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(2, "NOVAK DJOKOVIC", (byte) 26, "Belgrade, Serbia", "Monte Carlo, Monaco", (short) 188, (byte) 80, "Boris Becker, Marian Vajda", sdf.parse("22.05.1987")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(1, "RAFAEL NADAL", (byte) 27, "Manacor, Mallorca, Spain", "Manacor, Mallorca, Spain", (short) 185, (byte) 85, "Toni Nadal", sdf.parse("03.06.1986")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(7, "TOMAS BERDYCH", (byte) 28, "Valasske Mezirici, Czech", "Monte Carlo, Monaco", (short) 196, (byte) 91, "Tomas Krupa", sdf.parse("17.09.1985")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(8, "STANISLAS WAWRINKA", (byte) 28, "Lausanne, Switzerland", "St. Barthelemy, Switzerland", (short) 183, (byte) 81, "Magnus Norman", sdf.parse("28.03.1985")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(4, "ANDY MURRAY", (byte) 26, "Dunblane, Scotland", "London, England", (short) 190, (byte) 84, "Ivan Lendl", sdf.parse("15.05.1987")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(5, "JUAN MARTIN DEL POTRO", (byte) 25, "Tandil, Argentina", "Tandil, Argentina", (short) 198, (byte) 97, "Franco Davin", sdf.parse("23.09.1988")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(10, "JO-WILFRIED TSONGA", (byte) 28, "Le Mans, France", "Gingins, Switzerland", (short) 188, (byte) 91, "Nicolas Escude & Thierry Ascione", sdf.parse("17.04.1985")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(6, "ROGER FEDERER", (byte) 32, "Basel, Switzerland", "Bottmingen, Switzerland", (short) 185, (byte) 85, "Stefan Edberg, Severin Luthi", sdf.parse("08.08.1981")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(9, "RICHARD GASQUET", (byte) 27, "Beziers, France", "Neuchatel, Switzerland", (short) 185, (byte) 75, "Sergi Bruguera and Sebastien", sdf.parse("18.06.1986")));
            dataHashSet.add(new Players(3, "DAVID FERRER", (byte) 31, "Javea, Spain", "Valencia, Spain", (short) 175, (byte) 73, "Jose Francisco Altur", sdf.parse("02.04.1982")));

            sortDataModel = new SortDataModel<Players>(new CollectionDataModel<Players>(dataHashSet));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayersBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public SortDataModel<Players> getSortDataModel() {
        return sortDataModel;
    }

    public String sortDataByRanking() {

        sortDataModel.sortThis(new Comparator<Players>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Players key_1, Players key_2) {
                if (sortType.equals("asc")) {
                    return key_1.getRanking() - key_2.getRanking();
                } else {
                    return (-1) * (key_1.getRanking() - key_2.getRanking());
                }
            }
        });
        sortType = (sortType.equals("asc")) ? "dsc" : "asc";
        return null;
    }
}
```

with `SortDataModel.java` as:

```
public class SortDataModel<T> extends CollectionDataModel<T> {

    CollectionDataModel<T> model;
    private Integer[] rows;

    public SortDataModel(CollectionDataModel<T> model) {
        this.model = model;    
        initRows();
    }

    private void initRows() {
        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
        if (rowCount != -1) {
            this.rows = new Integer[rowCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) {                
                rows[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    public void sortThis(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
        Comparator<Integer> rowc = new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer key_1, Integer key_2) {
                T key_1_data = getData(key_1);
                T key_2_data = getData(key_2);
                return comparator.compare(key_1_data, key_2_data);
            }
        };
        Arrays.sort(rows, rowc);

    }

    private T getData(int row) {
        int baseRowIndex = model.getRowIndex();

        model.setRowIndex(row);
        T newRowData = model.getRowData();
        model.setRowIndex(baseRowIndex);

        return newRowData;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {

        if ((0 <= rowIndex) && (rowIndex < rows.length)) {
            model.setRowIndex(rows[rowIndex]);
        } else {
            model.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRowAvailable() {
        return model.isRowAvailable();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return model.getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public T getRowData() {
        return model.getRowData();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowIndex() {
        return model.getRowIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getWrappedData() {
        return model.getWrappedData();
    }

    @Override
    public void setWrappedData(Object data) {       
    }
}
```

After debugging I came to know that the rows integer array will be filled with the integers starting from 0 to the size of your collection which is to be sorted(rows in this case) minus one.

[image]

Next I see that he has overridden the `setRowIndex` method to replace the default row index.

Firing a GET request results in the calling of this overridden method multiple times from

[image]

to 0, 1, 2, 3…. Finally again -1 in the end,
[image]

1. What exactly is the use of this method? Just couldn't get the point of the author?
2. As you can see that hashset was intialized with adding 10 items. After firing the GET request I see only 5 items. Why?

**GET:**

[image]

Clicking on the "Ranking" link to sort them:

**POST:**

[image]

Why 5 records only?

I am using Glassfish Application Server 4.1.1 with Mojarra 2.2.12 being used internally.

**View**

```
             <h:dataTable value="#{playersBean.sortDataModel}" var="t" border="1">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink action="#{playersBean.sortDataByRanking()}">
                                Ranking
                            </h:commandLink>                        
                        </f:facet>
                        #{t.ranking}
                    </h:column>.....

            ....

             </h:dataTable>
```